# IntelliSense автозаполнение окончания

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Есть ли у IntelliSense функция автозаполнения окончания словосочетания без закрытия меню выбора? Например я хочу набрать - `XmlSchemaComplexType`, набираю `XmlS` нажимаю Tab и IntelliSense закрывается. Стрелками листать целый список вниз до нужного значения неудобно, да и постоянно набирать `XmlSchemaComplex` тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, при выборе элемента из списка, список всегда закрывается.

Вы можете принудительно вновь отобразить список IntelliSense, нажав сочетание `Ctrl` + `J` или `Ctrl` + `Space`. Наберите первые буквы команды, список сам отобразит подходящие элементы.

Comment: Ctrl + Space вероятно :)

Comment: @ИгорьВисков да и так тоже можно :)

Answer (score 0):

Это не обязательно, достаточно набрать XmlSCoT и IntelliSense сама найдет нужный тип. Она умеет определять по частичному совпадению.

Comment: Этот способ не работает VS2012

Comment: Это лечится использованием ReSharper`а